# Default Universal App template causes XAML designer crash

Tags: c#, visual-studio, xaml, windows-10-universal

I have VS2015 community and also SDK 10 and tools.
When I open blank universal app , I get this message in visual designer : [message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BHGOK.png)

I disable developer mode and reset computer but still I have problem.

Please Help.
Thanks.

Comment: Please copy the text of the message into your question. this will help other people to find the question and hopefully the answer

Comment: Ok , Thanks. I will do that.

Comment: There is a similar case [here](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/fe4f3ea0-245d-4189-988d-6759d1d726d2/uwpxaml-designer-failed-to-load-on-vs2015-pro-update-2?forum=visualstudiogeneral&prof=required) in MSDN. As the answer said, Please check if the Tools(1.3 or 1.4)  correctly installed.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem with Visual Studio 2012 when building a WPF application. The build succeeds but the intellicence dosen't work for xaml in this case. I went to Tools->Extentions and Updates and installed Visual studio Update and it started working. Not sure if this helps but please give it a try.

Comment: Thanks , I will do it!

Comment: This is because you have a particular update to Visual Studio 2015 (my guess is Update 2), but you do not have the matching Windows 10 Tools build. You could go to Add/Remove program, choose Change -> Modify, and then make sure that you have selected the latest version of both Visual Studio 2015 Update 3 and the Windows 10 tools.